# CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217 while using Microsoft graph client sdk 2.8.0

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

on 8th april out of 600k requests we started getting 30k errors from microsoft graph client error com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: InvalidAuthenticationToken Error message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217
This was all sudden, Can anyone help with root cause ? We did not make any changes in the code and we are using 2.8.0 version for this client sdk library

Comment: Would you try parsing the token using https://jwt.ms/ to see if there is something wrong with it as the error indicates? Also what sdk are you using ?

Comment: It would help if you can go into a bit more detail about what request you’re trying to do. And how you’re requesting the token.